# Can I change the process.env.NODE_ENV in dev?

Tags: react-native

I'm using a node package API client in my react-native project that uses the process.env.NODE_ENV to determine whether to return development or production data.  I'd like to test it in my dev environment (simulator) against the production database (it's read-only and the data greatly differs between dev and prod).

From what I can tell from this:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/39#issuecomment-131415769
process.env.NODE_ENV is set to development by default when the dev flag is true.

I've tried setting the NODE_ENV to production in my environment but it isn't picked up in the actual simulator (it still says development).

Is there some way to specify this when starting up or using run-*?

Comment: I'm current searching for a solution to this as well.  I'll post if I find a good resolution.

Comment: Did either of you find a solution? It seems that the node instance is spun off by a separate process and it doesn't pass through environment variables. I've heart other people initializing environment variables in their files, but that seems like a hack to me, as I only want this in my dev environment and not production.

Comment: I haven't - still using a workaround. :-(

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppDelegate.m` startup (before calling `jsBundleForBundleRoot`), add this:

```
[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings].enableDev = false;
```

Or for Android, it should be something like this (untested):

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("js_dev_mode_debug", false);
```

Note that these change the defaults, which I believe exist beyond the execution of your app. So you'll probably need to run them again with `true` to reset them back to the default values.